# Filling a numpy array from v, (x, y) arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have used Python code for populating entries in a Numpy 2D array from three arrays V, X, Y, where

A[X[i],Y[i]] = V[i]

Unfortunately, I've forgotten what process this is called (I tried Googling "numpy array from index arrays", no luck) and what specific function/constructor to call.  Also, does it generalize to 3D, N-D?

Comment: I think that's called "(advanced) array indexing", and it surely does generalise to N dimensions: you can do stuff like `A[a,b,c,d,e,f] = 5` no problem. "Advanced" is in quotes because it'll only apply if one of `X[i],Y[i]` is an array or list

Comment: Sounds like you just need `A[X, Y] = V`